# how to click a web button having only ID using VBA

Tags: vba, button, web

I'm trying to click this button (in the code at the end)

The thing is that, as you can see, I only have the ID, so I can't use `IE.Document.getElementsByName("xxxx").Item` or `IE.Document.getElementsByTAG("xxx").Item` which are the code I usually use to click a button.

Can anyone help me?

Many thanks in advance

```
    <TD id=copyCell>
      <BUTTON id=copy title="Copy grid to clipboard" class=dbnetgrid><IMG 
      id=copyImg 
      src="http://mxfrvwwinpro001.mx.corp/tsnet1/images/copy.gif"></IMG>
      </BUTTON>&nbsp;
    </TD>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `IE.Document.getElementById("xxx").click`.

Comment: thank you, i've already try it but still, it gives me an error (without "with" block")

Comment: Can you tell me what your `IE` variable is? Mine was created using `Set IE = CreateObject("HtmlFile").Script`.

Comment: I create it using: Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")

Comment: Are you sure GetObject is returning a valid IWebBrowser2 object? Inspect the variable in the VBA editor by going to the View menu, and enabling Locals Window.

Comment: Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")

IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "http://mxfrvwwinpro001.mx.corp/tsnet1/authentication/login.aspx"

Do While IE.busy
    DoEvents
Loop

Comment: IE.Document.getElementById("TBUserName").Value = "xxxxx"
IE.Document.getElementById("TBPasswd").Value = "xxxxx"
Set a = IE.Document.getElementsByName("BLogon").Item
a.Click

Do While IE.busy
    DoEvents
Loop

IE.Navigate "http://mxfrvwwinpro001.mx.corp/......"
 
Do While IE.busy
    DoEvents
Loop
 
Set b = IE.Document.getElementById("copy")

Comment: then, b gets the value "Nothing"

Comment: Print out `IE.Document.DocumentElement.OuterHTML` (to file or immediate panel since it might be too long for MsgBox; whichever is more convenient) and make sure that object exists. Sometimes they are added to the page dynamically and you won't see them until it happens.

Comment: Many thanks Hao Laoshi, i can't make it work but it seems to be a permission issue.